# Is this Huu-kikra bird race balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, homebrew-review, races

I have figured out that making homebrew races is rather fun and lets my creativity flow free. Any suggestions for fixes or suggestions, for this homebrew race of bird-like people, to make it balanced and viable? Or is its base concept even balanced to begin with?

***"HUU-KIKRA"***

**Ability Score Increase.** Your Constitution increases by 2, and either your Charisma or your Dexterity increases by 1

**Age.** Huu-Kikra reach maturity at about the age of 5 years old and average life span is 450 years tho they can live for up to 710 years.

**Alignment.** Huu-Kikra are usualy helpful by nature and a curious people. They tend to be of Lawful alignments.

**Size.** Huu-Kikra are often about 4 feet tall but can be up to about 5 foot 2 inches tall and weigh about 50-80 pounds. They are often stocky. Your size is small.

- **Size modifier 5d4**
- **Height = 3 feet + your size modifier in inches**
- **Weight in pounds = 20 + (1d6 x your size  modifier)**

**Speed.** Your walking speed is 20ft.

**Eyes of the Dark** Thanks to your night-made eyes, you are able to see in darkness perfectly and discern bright colours in dim and dark light. The range of darkvision is 120ft.

**Form of Huu** You can as a bonus action transform both your arms into wings that are twice the length of your body. When this form is active you have a fly speed of 60 feet and grow 1 foot in height. When you transform you drop what is in your hands onto the ground and cannot pick things up with your wings.
This ability can be used an amount of times equal to your proficiency bonus. The ability can be deactivated with a bonus action . You cannot fly while wearing Heavy armor

**Grace of owls** You have proficiency in either the "Sleight of Hand" or "Stealth" skill.

**Talons** You are proficient with your unarmed strikes, which deal 1d4+STR slashing damage on a hit. (Can be used in both Huu and base form). You can use your talons to use weapons but this will give disadvantage.

**Thick feathers** You are resistant to Cold damage but vulnerable to Fire damage.

**Feather of the night** You can use a bonus action to fire a feather from your arms or wings at an enemy you can see within 30ft, of you. Ranged weapon attack. Feather deals 1d4+Dex Piercing damage. This requires one free hand, but can be used in "Form of Huu"

**Languages.** You can speak, read and write Common, Auran and either Dwarven, Gnomish, Elvish or Halfling.

Comment: Can you give your own comments on if you think this is balanced and where you might see issues?

Comment: In addition to your own comments on the design, you might want to address why the existing bird folk options aren't satisfactory to you.

Comment: Ok, apparently this went unnoticed, but you should not make edits in response to answers. That invalidates answers, becomes incredibly messy and is counter to how we operate. I'm gonna begin to untangle which answer was what version and what is invalidated or not. As a compromise, I'd say we lock in the current version of the homebrew itself and ask answers to address it. I would still like to see the additions requested above.

Comment: @Pyrotechnical Thank you for providing me with that i will try and keep that in mind for future posts and updates and try to not be as compulsive when posting. Making these excites me alot. Once again. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Let's begin by looking at the two "bird-races" we already have:

### Owlin

- Medium or Small size
- 30 ft. walking speed
- Darkvision 120 ft.
- Flying speed equal to walking speed, can't use if wearing medium/heavy armor
- Proficiency in Stealth

---

### Aarakocra

- Medium size
- 30 ft. walking speed
- Flying speed equal to walking speed, can't use if wearing medium/heavy armor
- Talons (1d6+STR slashing dmg) as unarmed
- At lvl 3, gain a 2nd lvl spell once per long rest (or with spell slots)

---

### How do they compare to yours?

- **Proficiency** and **Darkvision** just like the Owlin [**NOTE:** you should specify a range for Darkvision, even if yours is an improved version (which btw should have a different name to make it more clear it's not the same as everyone else)]
- Your version of **Talons** is severely underpowered. I'd suggest looking at the **Aarakocra** and use those stats.
- **Feather of the night** is unique, but still underpowered. Being able to do a ranged attack as a natural one is a pretty cool idea. For your players to take advantage of it, it needs to be decent though. 1d4 without any ability modifier bonus is an extremely ineffective attack. Throwing a rock will probably do more damage. So either add STR or DEX mod to it. Also, all thrown/ranged weapons have a second range (max range), which could be a nice addition.
- **Thick feathers** balances itself out. Fire is a bit more common than cold, so it's definitely not an overpowered trait.

---

**Form of Huu**
"*You can as a bonus action transform both your arms into wings that are twice the length of your body. When this form is active you have a flight speed of 60 feet and grow 1 foot in height. When you transform you drop what is in your hands onto the ground and cannot pick things up with your wings.*"

**The first issue** that I noticed is that you didn't mention how to turn this off. Is it a bonus action? is it an action? is it free?

Also, does the transformation last indefinitely or is there a maximum time for it? What happens if you fall unconscious? What happens if you die? Is there a daily limit?

A somewhat similar ability is **Shifting** from the Shifter race:

> **Shifting**: As a bonus action, you can assume a more bestial appearance. This transformation **lasts for 1 minute, until you die, or until you revert to your normal appearance as a bonus action.** When you shift, you gain temporary hit points equal to 2 x your proficiency bonus. **You can shift a number of times equal to your proficiency bonus, and you regain all expended uses when you finish a long rest.** [...]

I would strongly suggest to consider doing something similar, but even if you decide to leave it without any limit (time or uses), you **need** to specify what kind of action it takes to turn back to normal.

**The second issue** is what is this intended for?

The way you wrote it, it makes it seem you no longer have access to your hands. If that's the case, consider that no hands means no wielding weapons or shields, no object interactions (potions, tools, etc...), and no somatic components / holding your spell focus either. So all you can do is move, or attack with the **Feathers of the night** trait.

If this was by design, that's great. If not, you might want to change it. Also if by any chance you were imagining your bird using its talons to drop items or grab enemies, then you need to specify that's an option (otherwise they are treated as feet, so u can't do pretty much anything with it other than unarmed [talon] strikes).

What did you imagine this trait to be used for?

---

A couple extra things worth mentioning:

- Your race allows characters in medium/heavy armor to fly, unlike other flying races (including the Fairy) that don't.
- Other race's flying speed can be improved (since it's linked to walking speed) in several ways. Your trait doesn't benefit from walking speed improvements, meaning most features that improve speed wouldn't affect it (like Monk or Barbarian classes, Mobile feat, or some magic items)

Comment: I'd like to understand why this is getting downvoted, when it is an analysis of the racial abilities

Comment: I didn't downvote but while I think you did a good job comparing the individual traits, I don't think you compared the overall package of the race. It seems like Huu-Kikra has a lot of stuff going on in total, more than either of the other 2 you compare. Also there's Kenku!

Comment: K had forgotten about the armor thing, i will be doing some tweaks.

Comment: Thick Feathers doesn't balance itself out at all, it is horrible. Vulnerability affects you about twice as heavily as a resistance and fire is significantly more common than cold, this is a pretty bad nerf disguised as a balanced feature. It *was* balanced by other strong traits before the edits but now it makes for a very weak race

Answer (score 3):

### This race has too many features

I find this is an interesting design, slightly too powerful overall, and with two major issues:

The first issue is that it has **feature bloat**. Counting up I see a total of 6 special features, while most PHB races have maybe 2 or 3. You are cramming in too much stuff, and as nearly all of them are beneficial, it makes the race too powerful.

The second issue is that it **uses crippling features** to compensate for this feature bloat and get the power level back closer to balanced.

- For example, **vulnerabilty** to a common damage type like fire is a pernicious flaw. Such *situational*, strongly negative features are not a good way to balance an otherwise overpowered race, because they can lead to **unbalanced play experiences** -- when you are not suffering from fire attacks, it does not matter, when you are, you can die very easily.
- Taking away the ability to cast spells or use your normal weapons to offset more powerful flight likely makes the race's hallmark feature **less enjoyable to play**. There is a reason that the game's normal class features are nearly entirely positive: new toys are fun. Getting nerfed is less fun.<sup>1</sup>

I would definitely cut the resistance/vulnerability that seems unnecessary and is problematic, and the ranged attack and its overpowered damage output.

---

To the details: I normally use Detect Balance, but you state you do not like it, I will abstain from it here. Instead I will compare to the old Aarakocra from the *Elemental Evil Player's Compendium*, and the new one from *Mordenkainen's Monsters of the Multiverse* as an official race.

Let's first compare the features side-by side. I'll leave out **age** and **alignment** as they have minimal impact on balance.

| Feature | Aarakocra | New Aarakcra | Huu | Comment on Huu |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Creature Type** | Humanoid? | Humanoid | ? | **Even**. I'll assume Huu are humanoid too, it would be better to specify this, as it has an impact on vulnerabilty to many common spells. |
| **ASI** | +2 Dex +1 Wis | +2/+1 any two or +1 any 3 | +2 Con +1 Cha/Dex | **Even**. High Dex is not as valuable to you as you can wear medium armor in flight, but not having it makes you a weaker ranged attacker. You have a bit more flexibility than the old and less than the new. |
| **Walking Speed** | 25 | 30 | 20 | **Slightly weaker** but who cares, really. You will be flying most of the time. |
| **Size** | Medium | Medium | Small | **Slightly weaker**. Small creatures have some fringe advantages, but are limited in weapon selection. It's not a big difference. |
| **Languages** | 3 | 2 | 3 | **Even**. You have slightly more selection on the third language, but that has no impact on balance, as does language overall. |
| **Flight** | 50 feet, light armor, hands | 30 feet, light armor, hands | 60 feet, light & medium armor, no hands | **Even**. 60 is very fast and medium armor means you easily can have decent AC, but no hands means at least disadvantage on attacks or weaker damage. |
| **Talons** | 1d4 proficient | 1d6+strength bonus not proficient | 1d4+dex bonus proficient, can wield weapons at disadvantage | **Stronger**. Proficiency and ability bonus makes this stronger than either of the others. |
| **Extra feature** | - | *gust of wind* known, cast 1/day | darkvision 120' | **Stronger**. Superior darkvision out to 120' enables shooting unseen at many monsters in the dark and is much more useful than the weak *gust of wind*. |
| **Extra Feature 2: Feathers** | - | - | Ranged bonus action attack 30' 1d4+dex modifier | **Much Stronger**. Oviously much stronger than nothing, and very strong absolutely. It is entirely unbalanced to have a bonus action on level one that can be used every turn to add about 4-5 points of raw damage output. (The description is not mentioning proficiency here, not sure if that is on purpose.) |
| **Extra Feature 3** | - | - | cold resistance, fire vulnerability | **Much Weaker**. While superficially, resistance and vulnerabilty seem to balance, they really don't. See below. |
| **Extra Feature 4** | - | - | Proficiency in Stealth or Sleight of Hand | **Stronger**. Stealth in particular is one of the most often used skills. |

#### Flight

Your flight form may be technically limited to a few times per day, but as it has no duration limit, and as you do not need your hands if you are not a spellcaster, you can easily keep it up most of the time, so that limit is not a real one.

Flight of course is *extremely* powerful. Many opponents just have no recourse against it because they cannot fly and lack ranged or long range weapons and cannot attack back. So you can shoot them down at no risk, even with disadvantage, all you need is a lot of arrows. That is a boring experience after the first few times.

In addition, your flight form allows for medium armor and a decent AC against those opponents who could attack you (for Aarakocra you'd need a class with alternative routes to AC like a barbarian or monk).  Your flight is also very fast, and that is powerful in itself, as can be seen from nerfing the Aarakocra speed in the new version. We often cast *fly* not for the flight but for the increased speed.

Your flight form on the negative side has no hands, so you cannot cast any spells that require somatic components or use you either attack with disadvantage from the weapons, or are limited to the weaker attacks of your natural weapons. While this helps balance the power, it does not sound fun to play at all. To me this is just an worse solution to flight than the standard offered by Owlin and Aaracocra.

#### Vulnerability

This is my main issue with the class. A vulnerability and a resistance do not cancel each other out. Vulnerability can easily snuff out your character -- a fireball at level 5 means heavy damage on a normal character, but with vulnerability it spells death in most cases.  Detect Blanance recommends "Don't. Just don't" for this with good reason.

Because it is so bad, vulnerability helps to offset some of the feature bloat that makes the class otherwise stonger than the benchmark. But this is not a good way to do that. It would be better to keep the class simpler to begin with.

#### Bonus Action attacks

No published race has an unlimited bonus action attack from level one. Lizardfolk get a bonus action bite attack, but it is limited to proficiency bonus uses per long rest. This is just plain unblanced: Typcial characters on level one have a damage output of about 8-9 expected damage (1d8 with a one handed weapon or bow, plus a profiency bonus of +3). This adds another 4-5 points, an over 50% increase in damage that is entirely gravy and that no other race has access to.

---

1 There might be some class, loophole or exploit I overlook that would allow you to get around the downsides, or make them not matter. This would be another issue: a race is only as balanced as its most exploitable class combo, as people will find and play exactly that combo.

Answer (score -3):

### The version after the edits is basically unplayable

I have used the *Detect Balance* spreadsheet to assess this race:

- **Ability Score Increase** - +2/+1 is quite standard for official races, Constitution is good for any character and choice of Dex/Cha works for a wide variety of builds. **+12 points.**
- **Age, Alignment** - fluff, doesn’t effect the balance. **+0 points.**
- **Size** - Small characters have a couple of situational advantages and disadvantages but nothing significant enough to affect the race’s balance. **+0 points.**
- **Speed** - 20 feet is very slow, *Detect Balance* rates it at **-3 points**.
- **Darkvision** - this isn’t the standard darkvision which lets you see in darkness as if in dim light, it lets you see in the darkness perfectly, removing the disadvantage on Perception checks based on sight. Regular darkvision at 120 feet would be worth 4 points and the guidance is to double that if it allows perfect sight, making this worth **+8 points**.
- **Form of Huu** - Flight speed is a strong feature in general but limiting  this to once per long rest drastically reduces its usefulness. Not being able to hold anything in your hands while flying is a further nerf as it restricts you to just natural weapons if using this in combat. Can't be used with heavy armour which makes it unusable for a STR-based martial character. Worded this way, I assess it to be worth **+4 points.**
- **Grace of owls** - choice of one out of two proficiencies. *Stealth* is generally a better option than *Sleight of Hand*. According to *Detect Balance*, a fixed proficiency is worth 2 points, a choice of one from a list is worth 3 points. I think two is a limited enough number to choose from that it’s not worth an extra point, additionally they are both somewhat related, I am therefore rating this at **+2 points**.
- **Talons** - a disadvantage on using weapons in exchange for an unarmed strike of 1d4 + STR is more of a detriment than benefit. In addition, this scales with STR whereas the other natural weapon option scales with DEX, a character is **highly** unlikely to have both good DEX and STR, making either this feature or *Feathers of the night* quite weak. In my opinion, this is worth around **-6 points.**
- **Thick feathers** - a resistance and a vulnerability. In my opinion this is much more of a detriment than it is of benefit, for one, a vulnerability is a much bigger deal than a resistance (for an attack that does x points of damage a vulnerability adds another x for 2x total, whereas resistance only subtracts 0.5x, for a total taken of 0.5x), second, fire damage is more common than cold. Fire vulnerability is rated at -20 points, whereas Cold resistance at +3, bringing the total for this trait to **-17 points**.
- **Feather of the night** - a ranged natural weapon, 1d4 + DEX isn't bad, but as mentioned above, doesn't work well with *Talons* which are STR based, after the clarification that it does require a free hand to use I am rating this at **+2 points**.
- **Languages** - Common + two other, not unusual for races, this is valued at **+1 point**.

The total value for this race ends up at **3 points**. This race is borderline useless. You have a creature that is slow, has vulnerability to fire, one of the most common damage types, gets disadvantage on using **ALL** weapons, which in practice constrains it to only its natural weapons. It theoretically has 2 but in practice will have to choose one to use all the time since they work off two abilities that are usually exclusive, only very rarely will you see a character with both high DEX and STR. The only strong feature of this race really is the Darkvision, the others are minor. In my opinion this isn't enough to balance the race out. It won't work with the majority of classes.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of "Detect Balance", so I don't regularly use it. That being said, don't you think Talons and Feather of the night should be worth less points?
They don't just do only 1d4, but they also don't benefit from any ability score (at least not worded that way) which makes them notably weaker than any other natural weapon trait.
Also shouldn't darkvision be worth more, considering he didn't specify a range limit?

Comment: @Mr_Bober talons are exactly the same as on aarakocra, the same flat d4 and aarakocra’s are rated at 1 point, feathers of the night - perhaps but it *is* a ranged natural weapon, a pretty rare thing for a PC character, not needing a free hand to fire it is nice as well but maybe it should be worth 2 points instead. The darkvision i am assuming is an oversight until OP clarifies it, if it’s intended to be without a range limit then absolutely it’s going to be worth more

Comment: They used to be, but with the new releases they became 1d6+STR, just like the Centaur's hooves or the Lizardfolk bite.. the new standard is 1d6+STR for all natural weapons.
As for the "not needing a free hand", that's fair. I didn't realise he can also use it while not in flying form, so technically he can be wielding stuff and use that attack

Comment: It's crazy to me that 60ft flight is worth the same as fire vulnerability. I think detect balance probably needs a modifier for number of features too. This race has more than normal and I think that indicates an issue.

Comment: The dark vision was meant to be unlimited range but I figured that it was kinda dumb. The cand discern colors in daylight is meant to be as dark vision in dim light. And i have done some tweaking to the abilities due to comments.

Comment: While I don't mind using detect balance I can't ever see me saying that a race with a vulnerability is balanced.

Comment: @SeriousBri there aren't any in the official content but there's no inherent reason for it to not be if it's offset by other features strong enough and 60 feet flight with no armour restrictions *is* pretty awesome. Fwiw I would be happy to play this race even with the vulnerability. Edit: wrote this before seeing the changes OP made to the race, a brief look tells me they nerf the race quite significantly and make it no longer balanced, I'm going to include them in my answer later

Comment: A quick misunderstanding you might have with the talons. The disadvantage on using weapons only comes up when you wield them using the talons. As I understand it (meaning, talons are leg/feet natural weapons) you can use your arms to wield weapons normally, without any disadvantage. This trait should not be worth negative points, since it only gives another option without nerfing existing ones (wielding with talons might be useful when flying and your hands aren't available, which is probably the intended use for this perk).

Comment: Another thing about this though, is that it could create some weird interpretations of the text. Can you wield weapons both with your hands and talons, while on the ground? I can hardly imagine a bird person using one sword in each hand and one dagger in each talon, for instance (now that I think about it, it sounds either very scary to face, or straight up ridiculous), but RAW for now it would work.

Answer (score -4):

### This race can fly.  The major difference between it and other flying races is that it can't hold things (spell components, longbows,  etc) while it does so, but can go faster than other flying races.

Flying Speed is rarely a big issue.  Being in the air is usually good enough to avoid whatever is coming at you, as many D&D 5e printed encounters entirely lack ranged options, and many monsters also lack any ability to hurt something flying (or something fast) which leads to issues for DMs with flying characters in the party.  Especially those that are spellcasters or archers.  If this character is needing to chase an enemy while shooting cantrips at them, the 60' flying speed will be very helpful but otherwise it likely won't come up very often.

This race is less powerful as an archer than races that can fly and hold things.  It's as powerful if a caster that doesn't need much in the way of spell components (or the DM rules you can tug them out with your beak from a specially made bandoleer or w/e).  As a melee guy, the flying doesn't hurt but doesn't help as you can't hold a weapon and fly around.

Nothing about the race is particularly notable except for the flying, and flying is hard to value as most of the time DMs will counter the flying characters in some manner and not just create and iterate encounters that get shot to pieces from the sky.  Ergo it's balanced, in the sense that flying races already exist and it doesn't do anything they don't already do, and it's viable, in the sense that being able to fly is pretty good.

Comment: Actually there are more important differences:
1. This race doesn't prevent flight with medium/heavy armor, while the others do
2. They require a bonus action to fly, others can do it for free
3. Their flying speed can't be improved, while other races can improve it with classes, feats, and magic items (for example, an Owlin / Aarakocra lvl 18 Monk, with Mobile feat and Boots of Speed gets an astonishing 140 ft. flying speed, while this guy would still be at 60 ft.)

Also worth mentioning, the older version (from EE Player's Companion) of Aarakocra had 50 ft. flying speed

Comment: I think you are underestimating the value of flight speed. Unlimited flight with no restriction on armour is *amazing* and especially at lower levels can make a character nigh untouchable